# Accessing Controller Property from VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I have a Controller property that displays the record type name of a Case.

I just need to display the record type during Case Creation or Editing.

This should be a read only as such I decided to use the outputField tag for this.

```
 <apex:outputField value="{!sRTName}"/>
```

While saving the page itself I am getting an error as below.

```
Error: Could not resolve the entity from <apex:outputField> value binding '{!sRTName}'. <apex:outputField> can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable.
```

This is the property defintion in the controller

```
public String sRTName{get{return sRTName;} set{sRTName=value;}}
```

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@RisingPhoenix You can use `<apex:outputField>` only with SObject or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable. So in your case you should use `<apex:outputText>` instead of `<apex:outputField>`